# Register global request handler for all blueprints in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to register `before_request` and `after_request` handlers for all routes (in all blueprints) in Flask.

It's easy to register for a single blueprint:

```
main = flask.Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.before_request
def do_something():
    flask.request.my_value = 'my_value'
```

However, I don't know how to accomplish this for *all* Blueprints.  Specifically because I use a factory function to create my app:

```
def create_app():
    from my_package.blueprints.main import main
    from my_package.blueprints.user import user

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(user)

    return app
```

Ideally I would like to keep all of my middleware functions in a separate file with something like a `root` or `super` Blueprint.  Alternatively I suppose I could iterate over all Blueprints on the `app` object and register these handlers on each, but that seems redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1

You can use `before_app_request` and `after_app_request` to register **global** handler on any blueprint:

```py
@any_bp.before_app_request
def before_all_request:
    pass
```

### Method 2

Use `before_request` and `after_request`, but register request handler direct for `app` in application factory:

```py
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.before_request
    def before_all_request:
        pass

    return app
```